# Aggregate Elastic search query for multiple fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm writing an elastic search query the payload looks like

**"userData": [ 
{ 
"subject1":1234,
"subject2":678
}
]**

I have written a query which works perfectly fine if I want to  get the avg of a single field

Query :

```
{ 
  "aggs": { 
    "student_data": { 
      "date_histogram": { 
        "field":"@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval":"minute"
      },
      "aggs": { 
        "marks_avg": { 
          "avg": { 
            "field":"subject1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to get the average of subject2 also.

somewhat like :

```
"avg": { 
    "field":"subject1",
    "field":"subject2"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query using multiple aggregations should work:

```
{ 
  "aggs": { 
    "student_data": { 
      "date_histogram": { 
        "field":"@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval":"minute"
      },
      "aggs": { 
        "subject1_avg": { 
          "avg": { 
            "field":"subject1"
          }
        },
        "subject2_avg": { 
          "avg": { 
            "field":"subject2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I needed the subject1 array also in the output